# scapy no answer to fragmented tcp get

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to make a quick TCP connection with scapy. in this scenario I will be using HTTP and I expect the server to redirect me and close the connection. and this works for the most part. after opening the connection, I send a HTTP GET and get a redirect reply.

But now I want to fragment my get. I used scapy's fragment method to split the payload and I am sending each of them out. I captured the sequence with tshark and everything looks fine:

`Capturing on eth1
  0.000000    10.80.0.8 -> 30.0.0.1     TCP 40823 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0
  0.003022     30.0.0.1 -> 10.80.0.8    TCP http > 40823 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=0 Win=2048 Len=0 MSS=1024
  0.020846    10.80.0.8 -> 30.0.0.1     TCP 40823 > http [ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0
  0.042347    10.80.0.8 -> 30.0.0.1     IP Fragmented IP protocol (proto=TCP 0x06, off=0)
  0.562284    10.80.0.8 -> 30.0.0.1     IP Fragmented IP protocol (proto=TCP 0x06, off=16)
  1.079767    10.80.0.8 -> 30.0.0.1     IP Fragmented IP protocol (proto=TCP 0x06, off=32)
  1.599802    10.80.0.8 -> 30.0.0.1     HTTP GET /index.php HTTP/1.1 
  1.603175     30.0.0.1 -> 10.80.0.8    TCP http > 40823 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=44 Win=2048 Len=0
  1.603245     30.0.0.1 -> 10.80.0.8    HTTP HTTP/1.1 302 Moved temporarily 
  3.648274     30.0.0.1 -> 10.80.0.8    HTTP [TCP Retransmission] HTTP/1.1 302 Moved temporarily`

The way I send my packets in scapy is using `srp(pkt,timeout=0.5,multi=1)`. but this seems like it does not work with IP fragments as it does not find a response to the final fragment being send, despite there being 3 (ACK, redirect and retransmit)
Scapy will print:

`Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
..
Received 2 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets`

(it only received 2 because it only waits for 0.5 seconds and the retransmit comes much later)

is there a way to tell scapy to capture these packets as valid answers? or somehow return the "invalid" answers too?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: as of 2.4.3, Scapy supports HTTP defragmentation. See https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/http.html**

You can do:

```
sniff(session=TCPSession)
```

Which will defragmenting them automatically. Note because TCP fragmentation is protocol-specific, this currently only supports HTTP.

**Original answer:**

Fragmented answers are currently not supported in scapy: you can easily send fragmented packets, but won’t be able to receive easily their answers.

Scapy expects for each packet that is send a unique answer, when using `srp`
This means that if several packets generate only one answer (fragments) it won’t get them.

You can report this on the scapy github page as an Issue, to get it worked on / status on it